# How to check if String contains a date in a SimpleDateFormat and retrieve the date?

Tags: java, string, date, contains, simpledateformat

My code thus far:

```
String string = "Temp_2014_09_19_01_00_00.csv"  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
```

How can I check if the String contains a date? How can I retrieve this date? Any direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using regex to do what you want(You might want to research regex on your own):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
    String string = "Temp_2014_09_19_01_00_00.csv";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    Date tempDate = null;
    if(m.find())
    {
        tempDate = format.parse(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println("" + tempDate);
}
```

The regex looks for `4digits_2digits_2digits` then it takes that match if it finds one and tries to convert it into a date.  If it doesn't find a match then `tempDate` will be `null`.  If you want to bring in the `timestamp` also you can do that too.